# Mongodb: Sort by custom expression

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

How to sort results by a custom expression which I use in `find`?

The collection contains documents with the following attributes for example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ef1cd704b35c6d6698f2050"),
    "Name" : "TD",
    "Date" : ISODate("2021-06-23T09:37:51.976Z"),
    "A" : "19.36",
    "B" : 2.04,
}
```

I'm using the following `find` query to get the records with `Date` since "2022-01-01" and the ratio between `A` and `B` is lower than `0.1`:

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').find(
    {
            "experationDate" : 
            {
                    $gte: new ISODate("2022-01-01 00:00:00.000Z")
            },
            "$expr": 
            {
                "$lte": [ 
                            { "$divide": ["$A", "$B"] },
                            0.1
                        ] 
            }
            
    })
```

Now, I can't find the right way to sort the results by this ratio.

Comment: You can use an aggregation query to do all these tasks. The `$addFields` stage can be used to calculate the derived value _and_ the [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) will let you sort on the calculated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` in this way:

Search the documents you want using `$match`, add a field named `ratio` and use it to sort. And finally, not shown the field using `$project`:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
      "Date": { "$gte": ISODate("2020-01-01") },
      "$expr": { "$lte": [ { "$divide": [ "$B", { "$toDouble": "$A" } ] }, 0.1 ] } }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "ratio": { "$divide": [ "$B", { "$toDouble": "$A" } ] }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": { "ratio": 1 }
  },
  {
    "$project": { "ratio": 0 }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dze57d21sLd)

By te way, I've used other values to get results. Ratio between 2.04 and 19.36 is greater than 0.1. You have dividied `A/B` but I think you mean `B/A`.

By the way, this is not important, you can change values but the query will still works ok.

Also, maybe this could work better. Is the same query, but could be more efficient (maybe, I don't know) because prevent to divide each value into collection twice:

First filter by date, then add the field `ratio` to each document found (and in this way is not necessary divide every document). Another filter using the ratio, the sort, and not output the field.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": { "Date": { "$gte": ISODate("2020-01-01") } }
  },
  {
    "$set": { "ratio": { "$divide": [ "$B", { "$toDouble": "$A" } ] } }
  },
  {
    "$match": { "ratio": { "$lte": 0.1 } }
  },
  {
    "$sort": { "ratio": 1 }
  },
  {
    "$project": { "ratio": 0 }
  }
])
```

[Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3XHOBNsHDin)

Comment: Why do you need to use `$project` here?

Comment: I've added a new field `ratio` and I'm assuming you don't want to output the field.

Comment: Got that, Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! Also, I've updated the query to not divide twice. There is only one division and only for document whose `date` has been matched.